# Read text in cyrillic from file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, rake

I want to read text from files and save it in a database. So I wrote a sample code just to output the contents of my file to test. I have following rake task in my ruby on rails applications:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/string"

namespace :mktu do
  task :seed do
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/mktu/*.txt") do |file|
     puts "#{File.basename(file, ".txt")}"
     data = File.open(file, "r").read
     p data.encoding.name
     break_char = ";".encode("UTF-8")
     data.mb_chars.split(break_char) do |name|
      puts name.strip
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Here is my "rake mktu:seed --trace" output:

```
** Invoke mktu:seed (first_time)
** Execute mktu:seed
32
"UTF-8"
rake aborted!
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/home/dastan/Projects/rails/tmregister/lib/tasks/prepare.rake:32:in `split'
/home/dastan/Projects/rails/tmregister/lib/tasks/prepare.rake:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dastan/Projects/rails/tmregister/lib/tasks/prepare.rake:25:in `glob'
/home/dastan/Projects/rails/tmregister/lib/tasks/prepare.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Although my output shows that the file has UTF-8 encoding, it seems that `split` method can't find any matches because of encoding problems, so I get an empty array. How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try this: break_char = ";".encode("UTF-8") -> break_char = ";".force_encoding("UTF-8")

Comment: @pwned The same staff, no changes.

Comment: No. The ruby version is "ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to the first line of the Rakefile. You have to tell the ruby interpreter that you want to deal with UTF 8 characters...
Also using the force_encoding will give you better chances.

Comment: Did not help, thanks for trying. Nothing changed, the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution [on page](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/). So my code now looks like this:

```
task :seed => :environment do
  Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/mktu/*.txt") do |file|
    ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
    items = []

    puts "Creating mktu class #{File.basename(file, '.txt')}"

    klass = MktuClass.create!(:title => "Класс #{File.basename(file, '.txt')}")

    file = File.open(file, "r")
    data = ic.iconv(file.read)

    data.split(";").each do |item|
      MktuItem.create!(:name => item.strip, :mktu_class_id => klass.id)
      puts item
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for help!